# Intermediate Value Theorem Converse

Tags: calculus

I was asked if the converse to my books version of the intermediate value theorem is true. In the link is the theorem my book has. I was thinking about it and I think the answer is no, because the function may or may not be continuous. Not sure is that is correct or not.

LINK: http://tinypic.com/r/2j1szrc/9

Comment: The converse does not hold in general. But if we add monotone nature we get the converse. Thus if $f$ is monotone on an interval and satisfies the intermediate value property then $f$ is continuous on that interval.

Comment: [Conway's base thirteen function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) is about as discontinuous as a function can be, and yet it has the intermediate value property (in fact, it attains every real value on any open interval).

Answer (score 4):

The converse is not true.

Take for example the function $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [-1,1]$ such that $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ for $x > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. This function satisfies the intermediate value property but is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take some good, continuous function `f` with domain `[0,1]`. It follows intermediate value theorem.

We can intersect it, and glue counter example function `g` with domain `[0,1.5]` like this:

- `g` equals `f` from 0 to 0.5
- from 0.5 to 1: `g` behaves very bad, is not continuous and does everything it wants
- but from 1 to 1.5 it is again equal to `f` from 0.5 to 1

So `g` still follows intermediate value theorem, but can have any problems inside.